# branch prediction, and optimized code

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, embedded, branch, branch-prediction

I have following set of code blocks, the purpose of the both block is same.
I had to implement the 2nd block to avoid inverse logic and to increase the readability. 
BTW, in the production code the condition is very complex.

The question is - I know branching is bad, how much penalty I have to pay. 
Just as an extra info, please also consider, the probability of else branch is very high.

```
X = Get_XValue()
if (X != 5)
{
    K = X+3;
    .
    .
}
```

---

```
X = Get_XValue()
if (X == 5)
{
    /*do nothing*/
}
else
{
    K = X+3;
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all comes down to your compiler. A good optimizing compiler will detect that the `then`-clause in the second example is empty and reverse the test. Thus it will generate the same code for both cases so there should be no penalty at all.

As a side note, I can add that this was the case for all three compilers I tried (clang, gcc, and iccarm),

Comment: Thank you . I use Green Hills https://www.ghs.com/products/compiler.html

Comment: And , they claim - ".....most programs the Green Hills Compilers can improve speed and reduce size by at least a 20% compared to the both GNU and LLVM compilers."